# What does ? symbol mean if used after object type?

Tags: c#

Could someone please tell me what the ? symbol means in the following code:

```
  public Rectangle? Limits
    {
        get
        {
            return _limits;
        }
        set
        {
```

Answer (score 3):

It is syntactic sugar for specifying a [nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) type.

Answer (score 3):

It means it is a nullable type.

For example, `DateTime?` can be null, whereas `DateTime` cannot.